# Javafx project native packaging with Java 11

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, javafx-11

I am currently learning Java and javafx. Now I am able to make some simple Javafx applications so next step to me is to package my application with JDK and JavaFX so that it can be installed and run without having to install JRE.

I know that the way of making self contained package is quite different from what I can do in Java 8; and I tried to search some tutorials on this. But there are few discussions and tutorials about native packaging in Java 11. Those topics I can found are also kind of difficult for me. Can anyone give an instruction about what tools should I use (for developing I use Eclipse)? And how to create self contained application package from scratch?

Comment: See "Runtime images" in https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/.

Comment: I guess by "native" you mean you want to create a native executable, e.g. a `.exe` ?

Comment: @JornVernee yes .exe .dmg and .rpm